# What does 'ones' refer to?

Tags: grammar

> You are still left with your own face and figure, and you cannot trade those in for different ones.

In the sentence, what does the word 'ones' refer to?
Does it refer to 'faces and figures' or 'face and figure'?

Comment: What do you think the difference in meaning would be?  "face and figure" is already plural, which is why "ones" refers to them.

Comment: I think that 'different ones' means 'different faces and figures' in the sentence.

Answer (score 7):

In your example

> ones

refers to "face and figure"

> You are still left with your own face and figure, and you cannot trade those in for ***a*** different ***face and figure***.

Comment: To elaborate to address "faces and figures" in the question.  If it was just "face" or just "figure", it would be ",,,for a different one."  Each "one" refers to a different part of the anatomy, which is why "ones" is plural in the sentence.  But even if it was referring to just one part of the anatomy, the "different one" would mean "different example" or "replacement"; the meaning of "one", in this case, is not a reference to a numerical count.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I'd like to know whether 'ones' also refers to 'faces and figures'.

Comment: "A different face" = "a different one", "different faces" = "different ones"; "a different figure" = "a different one", "different figures" = "different ones"; "different face and figure" = "different ones".  I like "those bananas and apples" = "I like those ones".

Comment: I think 'different face and figure ' is an ungrammatical phrase. So it must be 'different faces and figures'. ' The phrase 'different ones' in my OP means 'different faces and figures'.

Comment: "A different face and figure" is perfectly grammatical and correct since one can only have a single face and **a single figure. The plural "ones" is for face *and* figure.

Answer (score 0):

> You are still left with your own face and figure, and you cannot trade those in for different ones.

`ones` redirect to `those`, and `those` redirect to `face and figure`.

Since `ones` is the plural form of `one`, the meaning you redirect to should be plural too.

Thus, the meaning is: `faces and figures` iirc.

Comment: "face and figure" is two things, so that's plural already - it doesn't have to be "faces and figures" :)

Comment: @psmears Actually, We do not know. If that was the case, it would mean 'faces and figures'.

Comment: I don't think you've understood what I'm saying. "Face" is one thing, "figure" is one thing, but "face and figure" makes *two* things, so needs a plural - so it could be *either* "faces and figures" *or* "face and figure". The fact that "ones" is present and is plural does *not* imply that it must be "faces and figures".